# Setup Wilcard SSL Certificates on IIS7 WITHOUT host headers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, ssl

I have created a site that dynamically creates sub domain addresses for customers when they create an account (without any changes to IIS).  For example, customer1.mysite.com, customer2.mysite.com, etc.

They all point to the same ip address using a DNS wildcard entry.

I handle all of the routing and mapping in custom MVC code.  (the site is MVC3 site using Razor).  According to IIS there is only one site.

Is it possible to dynamically enable each of the subdomain sites to be accessed via HTTPS using a wildcard certificate?  Has anyone done this?  Any tips to get it work?  Should it "just work?"

I have seen all of the posts about binding SSL certs to each site in IIS using host headers, but this does not apply here since it is just one site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that works, as long as you use the same domain.

You'll need a wildcard certificate. Your configuration should be similar to this:

```
<bindings>
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:mysite.com" />
  <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:mysite.com" />
</bindings>
```

Comment: I will try this out once I purchase the certificate.  Hopefully it will work.  Thanks for the response.